# Referential integrity : delete all children but not the parent [PostgreSQL]

Tags: postgresql, triggers, referential-integrity

I have an `imports` table that contains information on file imports that are done: idimport (`SERIAL PRIMARY KEY`), file name, import date, etc.

Several tables have a field `idimport INTEGER REFERENCES imports(idimport) ON DELETE CASCADE`.

To "unimport" a file, all I have to do is DELETE the row in the `imports` table.

The problem I'm facing is that some users tell me that they definitely imported a file but find no trace of the imported data. Usually, they unimported the file and forgot to reimport it but I have no proof of that (except the missing `idimport` which is far from enough).

So I would like to keep track of the imports that have been deleted. Ideally, I would like PostgreSQL to delete all the child rows, keep the parent (`imports`) row and I would mark that row as deleted, the user who deleted it and when the deletion was made (and maybe a reason for the deletion).

The idea I have here is to create an `ON DELETE` trigger that would memorize the "interesting" fields in the `imports` table, let the delete operation run and recreate an `imports` row with the interesting fields (including the `idimport`) and the ones I want to add.

But I want both "Before" (memorizing) and "After" (recreating the row) actions, so that would be two triggers and I don't know how I could make them communicate (the interesting fields).

Of course, I could either do this client-side or create a stored procedure but I'd prefer a completely integrated solution (working with `DELETE FROM imports WHERE idimport=12`)

Comment: You can access the whole deleted row in an `after` trigger though the `old` record (there is no need to memorize anything)

Comment: I would probably use a new separate table to archive deleted rows. This could be implemented in a single simple trigger.

Comment: You are looking for an audit trigger. See [here](https://eager.io/blog/audit-postgres/) or [here](https://www.garysieling.com/blog/auditing-data-changes-postgres) or [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus) or [here](http://okbob.blogspot.de/2015/01/most-simply-implementation-of-history.html) or [here](http://8kb.co.uk/blog/2015/01/19/copying-pavel-stehules-simple-history-table-but-with-the-jsonb-type/)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than burden the table with deleted rows, add an audit table that records whenever an import is deleted with a trigger. This table can be purged and truncated easily when necessary and does not burden your application.